# Get contents of a fixed memory location

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to access a certain location in memory and retrieve the contents of that memory location but the program seems to not work when I run it. I don't get any errors it's just a blank console screen. The first thing that came to my mind is that it would probably be a security breach to be able to access a memory location like this. Is that the reason or is my code wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int * pointer = 100;

    printf("%d", *pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accessing an arbitrary memory address is undefined behavior in C. Your program has probably crashed.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, because there's no reason to think that address `100` (`0x64`) of your process' address space is mapped to anything. It's outside of any assigned memory segnments, so I'm getting a segmentation fault every time. This actually isn't so much a C thing (C doesn't care about something like this), but it's your kernel that will take an issue. On a micro controller with direct access to memory (no virtual memory), this would actually work fine.

Comment: That's probably a kernel memory location, not readable from user mode.

Comment: The comments above are correct, however you can arbitrarily access memory locations in certain contexts. This is how the kernel prints text to the screen, by storing information at specific addresses, but you are not the kernel and the OS would likely stop you from doing so.

Comment: If you want to analyze the memory layout of your process's [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), you will have to use platform-specific functions. Therefore, please specify which platform (i.e. operating system) you are using, if you want us to tell you how you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory mapped registers are an integral part of embedded programming - but you need to know where in memory to prod - random locations are likely to generate random effects (due to undefined behaviour)!

For embedded compilers, usually there is a header file full of lines similar to:

`#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R  (*( ( volatile unsigned int * )0x40025400 ) )`

These (a) map registers appropriately and (b) hide the specific implementation.

Note the use of the `volatile` qualifier - any memory mapped access should be `volatile` qualified, otherwise there is scope for compiler optimisation to have an effect too!

Now we can use this name inside your code to read and write to that register (wherever it happens to be):

```
GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0xF0;
data = GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R;
```

The fact that your code results in "just a blank console screen" means it's not doing what you expect... your random location is causing random (undefined) behaviour.